# Check if a number is an integer with basic arithmetic

Tags: math, hopscotch-language

I am trying to create a function that checks whether a number is an integer or not. I've looked at all these other threads with the same question, and the only problem is:
I'm using [Hopscotch](https://www.gethopscotch.com/).

Because of this I only have access to the following operators:

```
Addition
Subtraction
Multiplication
Division
Exponents
Square roots
Sin
Cos
Basic Loops, Conditionals, and relational operators.
```

Is there any way to check if a number is an integer using only these?

Comment: @jongware "Decimal" here means that in base 10, floor(number) does not equal number.

Comment: Ah – you are testing for *whole numbers* (or, in computer lingo, "integers"). All decimal numbers are per their very definition "in base 10".

Comment: @Jongware Correct. Should I edit the question?

Comment: so you want an integer test without `mod` or `floor` (or `ceil`)? I guess you have relational operators at least?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Exactly. And yes, I do have relational operators.

Comment: @TreFox: You should definitely edit the question. At the moment it isn't actually asking what you want!

Comment: I don't know Hopscotch but I guess you could do a binary search: start with min and max value (i.e. some known integer value below and above the target) and binary search until `max - min == 1`, if your target is neither equal to min nor max, you have a non-integer number.

Comment: Thankfully, Hopscotch now has `round()` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repeat block will round your number to an integer. So if you repeat times the original number and increment a test number, you can check if they come out equal at the end.

[image]

As others have mentioned, for this to work the original number needs to be positive. To solve for this just multiply by -1 if the original number is less than 0.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Didn't think I'd get an answer from the co founder of Hopscotch :D Thanks for the answer with actual Hopscotch code samples!  Do you mind if I use your method and images on the forums? (With full credit to you)

Comment: Go for it. I love that people are using SO for Hopscotch questions.

Answer (score 1):

@scottysmalls answer will take about `N` steps, where `N` is your number.  If `N` is large, then this could take too long.  A faster approach would be to subtract out powers of two, which will end up taking about 2*log<sub>2</sub>`N` steps.  In pseudocode:

```
if value < 0 {
    value = -1 * value
}
powerOfTwo = 1
while powerOfTwo < value {
    powerOfTwo = 2 * powerOfTwo
}
while powerOfTwo >= 1 {
    if value > powerOfTwo {
        value = value - powerOfTwo
    }
    powerOfTwo = powerOfTwo / 2
}
if value > 0 {
    value was a decimal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
if value == 0{
    value was zero
}
else if value > 0{
    while value >= 1
       value = value - 1

    if value == 0
        was a positive non-zero integer
    else
        was a positive decimal
}
else {
    while value <= -1
       value = value + 1

    if value == 0
        was a negative non-zero integer
    else
        was a negative decimal
}
```